# django-admin to open a new project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am using this command:

`django-admin startproject Hello`

to initiate a new project, but I am getting the following error

```
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the   
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the     
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin startproject Hello
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String)  
   [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

just started with django and this is so frustrating

Comment: it should be django-admin startproject Hello, and not django-admin STRATproject Hello

Comment: ignore the spell mistake
still not working

Comment: @Ankita Basu -When you type "python", does the system terminal outside VS Code enter the python interactive window?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you dont have django installed. If you have already installed it, you should check if you are with your virtual enviroment (venv) activated. Check this doc: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/venv.html

Go to the project directory and try this:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then:

```
django-admin --version **(to check if it is installed)**
django-admin startproject Hello
```

Comment: not working i have added the path to the variable paths as well

Comment: and i am using windows the above you mentioned is for mac

Answer (score 0):

try to install the django in vscode after creating an virtual environment

```
(venv) c:\mycode\hello> $ pip install django
```

then:
check the version of django

```
(venv) c:\mycode\hello> $ django --version
(venv) c:\mycode\hello> $ django-admin startproject <projectname>
```